# promise failure scenario in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have changed the env property of my url to test my code locally.. It seems the error call back is not even getting called.
my code snippet-

```
            $scope.getfiles = function() {
            Api.file.query().$promise.then(
            function(result){ $scope.getfiles = result; },  //on success
            $scope.commonAjaxErrorHandling("Failed to get  File data.",true)  //on failure--> Always this line of  code is executing..
               );
             };
```

If I try with writing other error function. It is not even getting called

```
       $scope.getfiles = function(){
        Api.flatFile.query().$promise.then(
         function(result){ $scope.File = result; 
      },
     function (result) { // this block is not getting called
         if(result.status== 404){
             $scope.addErrorAlert("Service is down.Please try again later",true);
             return;
         }
     });
    };
```

Any reason for that? I tried out with catch as well.. but dint worked.

```
            FileServices.factory('Api', ['$res', '$loc',
            function($res, $loc){
            var contextPath = $loc.absUrl().split('/app/')[0];
            return {
            flatFile: $res(contextPath+'/app/config/flatFile/data', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', isArray:true},
            save: {method:'POST'},
            })
            };
           }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below and let us know if its working. I don't understanding why you are using `$promise` there?

```
$scope.getfiles = function() {
    // This service's function returns a promise
    Api.flatFile.query()
        .then(function(data) {
            // promise fulfilled                        
          }, function(error) {
            // promise rejected, could log the error with: console.log('error', error);
        });
};
```

Comment: I am  getting excpetion here if i remove $promise. (query(...).then is not a function)

Comment: Can you show me the code for Api.flatFile.query()? I guess Api is a service.... where you might be exposing $http or $resource